# initramfs - customize init script

Tags: nfs, initramfs

We have a cluster system with master and several nodes. I have set up a PXE netboot of ubuntu kernel 5.4.0-91 from the master. The nodes load the initramfs and end up in the busybox.

Now I want to customize the initramfs to automatically do the following task: the nodes shall mount a directory from the master via nfs and execute a script there.

How to properly implement that?

Comment: why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There are pxe-ready images available which work over NFS ... But to answer your question, the init script is a shell script - just place your commands inside this script, and pack it into your initrd.

Comment: First thing is to learn and understand how things work. I think there are constraints on where to put it in the init script. E.g. for nfs the network interface needs to be up and configured. As I can see there are several stages, like init-top, init-bottom, etc. There is also a nfs-script in /main/scripts...

Comment: You may as well customize the behavior with the parameters in the initramfs.conf. So what are the best ways?

Comment: since you mentioned ubuntu, I recently configured a live-dvd to boot over pxe - all I had to do is append those kernel parameters to the kernel arguments, since the ubuntu init script already has the proper handling of a nfsroot: ```ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=<ip-nfs-server>:/path/of/nfsmount```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have done this by using `insmod tftp` and setting the root correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and testing, I found the following solution:

1. In the init script, you can use the function `configure_networking` (defined in `scripts/functions`) to activate and configure the network devices via dhcp-client.
2. to mount an nfs-share use `mount -o ro,port=2049,nolock,proto=tcp -t nfs <server-ip>:/nfs-dir /some-dir`